# ProxyPassMatch not working

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass

I have a server running at localhost:3030 and I can access a number of web pages. When I do a wget on `localhost:3030/index.html`, I obtain the web page. Using a ProxyPassMatch, I was trying to redirect a request on `example.com/sparql/<something>` to `locahost:3030/<something>` but it is not working. I am using debian and configuration is as follows:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
   ProxyPass         "/sparql"  "http://localhost:3030/"
   ProxyPassReverse  "/sparql"  "http://localhost:3030/"
   ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  "localhost"  "example.com"
    ....
    <VirtualHost *:80>
```

When I am sending a request on `example.com/sparql/index.html`, the page is returning but none of the images and css files are being returned. Is there a problem with configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

Why use `ProxyPassMatch` for such a simple [**reverse proxy**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)? You could just...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ...
    ProxyPass         "/sparql/"  "http://localhost:3030/sparql/"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/sparql/"  "http://localhost:3030/sparql/"
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  "localhost"  "example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, if your content is at `http://localhost:3030/` there might be some hard coded content that refers to `/` instead of `/sparql/` in the HTML body. While it is possible to also alter the content with [mod_substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_substitute.html), that may lead to other problems. Therefore, it would be recommendable to **use a subdomain** instead of additional part to the path, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sparql.example.com
    ...
    ProxyPass         "/"  "http://localhost:3030/"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/"  "http://localhost:3030/"
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  "localhost"  "sparql.example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: actually, i made a mistake when writing the question, my intention is to forward all request from example.com/sparql/<something> to localhost:3030/<something> but using your answer and removing the /sparql from localhost:3030 isn't returning any images and css files

Comment: I updated my answer to contain solution for both situations.

Comment: thanks, for using a subdomain, it might be a little difficult in my case as i don't have hand on DNS servers